# how to handle error in reading file containing multiple languages

Tags: python, nlp

[data trying to read](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XeqRpIy_P95yKZkBQYRX_WHrZrxQfwTm/view?usp=sharing)
I have tried various ways still getting errors of the different type.

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('sampledata.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
  print (repr(line))
```

the other way I tried is

```
f = open(fname, encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape")
```

still no luck.any help?

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of `Pandas` supports xlxs.

```
file_name =  # path to file + file name
sheet =  # sheet name or sheet number or list of sheet numbers and names

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(io=file_name, sheet_name=sheet)
print(df.head(5))  # print first 5 rows of the dataframe
```

Works great, especially if you're working with many sheets.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: well the problem is different u can refer the link which i added above . after doing above we get the same type of error.

Comment: Can you add the errors you're getting to the question?